# alsamixer cannot open mixer: Invalid argument

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

No sound in Ubuntu 14.04 seems after upgrading kernel...
I googled solutions, but cannot solve my problem. And I enter the command `alsamixer` in terminal. The output is this: `cannot open mixer: Invalid argument`. Cannot fix it either.

The weird thing is that after I use `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` and start it by using `pavucontrol`. And when I play audio, the control panel has recognized it.

Screenshot in below:

[image: volume control]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Sound worked perfect in Windows 7 but not in Kubuntu 14.04. After many days of searching the Internet and trying all possible advices I have come up with a solution that finally helped me. No need to reinstall Ubuntu.

First I tried to uninstall all ALSA packages and stuff using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and install them again using

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Still didn't work even after numerous attempts of

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I read that ALSA has master audio channel muted by defaut after install. So I tried to unmute it using `alsamixer` command. Unfortunately it didn't work due to `Invalid argument` error.

The search continued and I stumbled upon a [website](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=123250) that has always been in search results but I paid no attention to it. It mentioned some file called `.asoundrc`. I looked for it and didn't find it on my system. Another [website](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#The_.asoundrc_file_format) said that you should manually create it (`/home/username/.asoundrc` for current user only, or `/etc/asound.conf` if you want to keep these settings for all users) and paste the following content in there:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw           
    card 0
}
```

After that I was able to open `alsamixer`. However, the screen was empty and didn't show any volume settings as expected.
[image: alsamixer with no volume settings]
Then I opened list of my sound cards with

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

It turned out that my laptop has two sound cards:

```
0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                     HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0344000 irq 28
1 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                     HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0340000 irq 16
```

Card 0 was set by default in the beforementioned `.asoundrc` file. I experimented and changed `0` to `1`. Afterwards `alsamixer` showed the volume settings I needed.
[image: alsamixer with muted Master channel]
Master channel was muted by default, as ALSA documentation [warned](http://alsa-project.org/~valentyn/Alsa-sound-mini-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.3). It was indicated by the letters `MM` above the `Master` label. I used the <kbd>↑</kbd> arrow key to increase the volume to 100%. But this wasn't enough. I also had to press the <kbd>M</kbd> key to unmute Master channel since increasing the volume does not unmute it automatically (taken from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer)). After pressing <kbd>M</kbd> the `MM` letters became `OO` which meant the channel was unmuted.
[image: alsamixer with unmuted Master channel]
And the sound has FINALLY appeared! Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit `alsamixer` and enjoy the variety of sounds and music on your Ubuntu, Kubuntu or whatever distro it is that you are using.

**Important note:** do NOT use `sudo alsa force-reload` command at all (as some websites suggest) because it mutes the Master channel again and you will have to repeat the unmuting procedure!

*P.S.:* These were a hard couple of days trying all possible things to be able to hear again. Of course I could give up and switch back to Windows 7 but my advice to you is do not look for easy ways. The Linux way is not for everyone but after completing that challenge it really feels like a hero.